# Android: Start animation when fragment is loaded

Tags: java, android, animation, kotlin

I've trying to implement custom fragment with loading animation. Same code works fine with activity, but not works with fragment.

Here my fragment layout code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="pw.osin.musicexpert.fragments.BusyFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_animation_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/vinyl" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_animation_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/message_data_is_loading"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryYellow"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My methods which I invokes in OnCreate method in fragment

```
private fun setAnimation() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Установка анимации")
    val drawable = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.context, R.anim.rotate_anim)
    mAnimationDescription?.setText(R.string.message_data_is_loading);
    mAnimationImage?.startAnimation(drawable)
}

private fun initViewItems(view: View?) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Поиск элементов View")
    mAnimationDescription = view?.findView<TextView>(R.id.animation_description);
    mAnimationImage = view?.findView<ImageView>(R.id.animation_logo);
}
```

My rotate animation code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:toDegrees="360" />
</set>
```

Here I attach my animation fragment to activity in OnCreate method

```
private var mTransaction: FragmentTransaction? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    attachFragment()
}

private fun attachFragment() {
    mTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    mTransaction?.add(R.id.main_activity_container, BusyFragment.newInstance("Получаем дату"))
    mTransaction?.commit()
}
```

Where I need to invoke my start animation method?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you seeing? Your fragment shows but doesn't animate? Does your text view get the correct text?

Comment: Hello, yes. My fragment is shows but doesn't animate.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [`onResume`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onResume()):

> Called when the fragment is visible to the user and actively running. This is generally tied to Activity.onResume of the containing Activity's lifecycle.

You want to run the animation when it can be visible in the first place, hence I suggest starting the animation in your fragment's `onResume` or override the `onFragmentsResumed` method in the activity that this fragment is attached to.

Comment: Thanks for reply. No, it's doesn't work for me. Can u review my code? May be it have any issues? For example setAnimation for fragment need to be different and something like that. My code on Kotlin, but it have no big difference with Java.

Comment: OnResume is a perfectly viable place to start the animation. I think you should check if the startAnimation method really works as you think (there are several ways of executing animations in android, and it sometimes might be tricky)

Comment: In Fragments onResume is tied to the Activity's life cycle. So if the Activity's onResume as already been called when the fragment is attached it won't be called.

Comment: Thx for reply, what I need to do in this case?